# Animation not working in ViewWillAppear

Tags: ios, animation, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a view and I want to start an animation once the view is navigated to. I tried to do it in ViewWillAppear but nothing happens, I have tried to add a delay to the animations but nothing happens. I thought of doing it in ViewDidAppear but it is not called...

Here is my code:

```
    public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
            {               
                if(ViewModel.ShouldOpenNotifications)
                {
                    OpenNotificationsSidebar ();
                    ViewModel.ShouldOpenNotifications = false;
                }
                base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

            }   

void OpenNotificationsSidebar ()
        {
            NotificationsView.Hidden = false;
            UIView.Animate (0.5, 1, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, () =>
                {
                    NotificationsView.Frame = new RectangleF (40, NotificationsView.Frame.Y, NotificationsView.Frame.Width, NotificationsView.Frame.Height);
                    MainTable.Frame = new RectangleF (-280, MainTable.Frame.Y, MainTable.Frame.Width, MainTable.Frame.Height);
                    MainTabBar.Frame = new RectangleF (-280, MainTabBar.Frame.Y, MainTabBar.Frame.Width, MainTabBar.Frame.Height);
                    SettingsView.Frame = new RectangleF (-280, SettingsView.Frame.Y, MainTabBar.Frame.Width, MainTabBar.Frame.Height);
                    MainTable.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
                    MainTabBar.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
                }, null);
            _isNotificationsOpen = true;
            SettingsSwipeView.Hidden = true;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        }
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I am using MvvmCross and just found the ViewDidAppearCalled event so now I am getting the ViewDidAppearMethod to fire but still the animation is not working. even If I set the delay to 10 seconds... The animation does get called and the properties are changed but nothing is showing on screen...

**Update2**
Currently the only thing that works is the following:

```
Task.Run(()=>
{
   Thread.Sleep(2500);
   RunDelegateInUiThread(()=>
      {
         OpenNotificationsSidebar();
      });
});
```

Comment: I don't know C#, but I'm pretty sure calling `base.viewWillAppear(animated)` at the end of your method is an error. Calls to the super method should always be the first call in a method. Try putting that at the beginning of your method. You may have also done the same in your `ViewDidAppear` method.

Comment: @doctordoder I have moved it. it is at the beginning. Still no go.

Comment: Please show use your ViewDidAppear code

Comment: @doctordoder What do you mean? The only code that works is the one that uses a thread and then calles the UIThread.

Comment: I mean, post the code you have for your `ViewDidAppear` method into your answer. Thread.sleep is a terrible solution.

Comment: @doctordoder I totally agree. What I have is the same as I posted for ViewWillAppear, before I introduced threads :)

Answer (score 2):

Put this in `viewDidAppear` instead.

Comment: The problem is that ViewDidAppear is not called... It only seem to get called when I navigate backwards.

Comment: @Amit, he means, make the 'v' in View lowercased.

Comment: is this a UIViewController subclass?

Comment: I am using Xamarin so the names are uppercase :)

Comment: how is the view controller being created?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is related with some sort of Delay when threads are active. This has been happening to me a lot since iOS 7. Try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // your code that calls the view. i.e.:
  YourViewController*  YourViewControllerObj = [[YourViewController alloc]
                                      initWithNibName:@"YourViewController"
                                      bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  // ... more code.
]);
```

Comment: you mean inside ViewDidAppear?

Comment: ViewDidAppear is part of your View Controller. I meant before you call your view controller. I've edited my comment to reflect the example.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason of Why viewDidAppear and why delay etc not needed :**  Autolayout constraints are not satisfied in viewWillAppear. After viewWillAppear viewWillLayout and DidLayoutSubviews are called to satisfy constrains. After this viewDidAppear is called. Where all constraint are well rest. then you should perform animations.